# C# contains method for white spaces

Tags: c#, if-statement, windows-phone-8, contains

I am having trouble checking for a specific value inside a list, using the contains method, it doesn't seem to be working correctly, is there perhaps another way to check for string values with spaces.

for example:

```
  string test = "Hello Stack Person";

  if(test.ToLower().Contains("hello stack person"))
  {
    //code to execute
  }
```

howevert my if statement doesn't take, am I doing something wrong?

thanx!

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What's the problem? The code works fine for me.

Comment: `"Hello Stack Person".ToLower().Contains("hello stack person")` is `true`. Are you sure these are the *exact* strings you're using?

Comment: You code works here (C#4/.NET 4.5). There is something else in your code that is affecting this.

Comment: That if statement should return `true` if those are the exact values you're using. Have you cut and pasted this code as I noticed you're missing a closing bracket `)` on the `if statement`, wild guess but worth a mention..

Comment: @DGibbs I assume the missing `)` is a typo: but then this code does work as quoted. Therefore it cannot be representative of the real problem code.

Comment: @Richard I had guessed as much but it's the only thing I can see wrong with the code. Therefore the issue must be with his data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should check if the characters you think are whitespaces are **really** whitespaces. If they were non-breaking spaces, then a simple comparison like you posted won't work. While I believe Unicode holds more possibilites, this should do the trick in most cases.

```
if (test.ToLower().Replace('\u00A0', ' ').Contains("hello stack person"))
{
    // code
}
```

Now I have no idea why would you even have to deal with non-breaking spaces this way as they are pretty much only used to render text properly. I've run into such issue once already nonetheless and it took me some time to realize what was the problem since both strings I was comparing *looked* the same to *me*.

Answer (score 0):

Use trim() to remove spaces

If you are using a List, use `Select`

```
var selection = list.Select(x => x.ToString()
                .Trim().ToLower() == "hello stack person");
```

To get true or false use `Any`

```
var result = list.Any(x => x.ToString()
                .Trim().ToLower() == "hello stack person");
```

Comment: How does `Trim()` help? `Contains` should return true if the parameter string is anywhere in the object string.

Comment: Updated answer. Try using any in the list to check if value exist

Comment: Maybe the `"hello stack person"` part needs trimming. It seems like these are not the actual strings used.

Comment: The first query will return a string in the list if found, that's not what the OP wants. The second is equivalent to his if statement with an added trim which is pointless when he is using `Contains`.

Comment: Hi, no it is not the exact string that I am using, however it is the same idea. well I am looping over a dictionary, in which I access the first element  and trimming it and checking if it contains the 3 letter word, but it doesn't work, but on all the single strings it does work

Comment: Give us a real example then. You are defining a string in the example and talking about a list, and then you are complaining how the trim() can help in my answer

Comment: I cannot give the exact string, so my entire thing is trying to access a item in a list's value and checking if it contains a 3letter string and its not working: if(mylist[i].person.Contains("Hello Stack Person"))

Comment: `1+2` equals `3`, so `4+5` should also equal `3`. It's the same idea after all, right? No, in these cases, the *exact* values *do* count. A lot.

Comment: I understand, unfortunately it contains client data, so I cannot give it, sorry I can only say it is a string containing 3 words

Comment: Before, you said "3letter string"... programming is about being very precise. All we can say is that `"Hello Stack Person".ToLower().Contains("hello stack person")` is `true` and the body of the `if` statement *will* be executed in *this exact* case. Now it's up to you, to find out, why in *your exact* case one string (toLower) does in fact *not* contain the other string. *Maybe* the other string has leading/trailing whitespaces, maybe one string has two spaces between the words where the other only has one... stuff like that.

Comment: `if(mylist[i].person.Contains("Hello Stack Person"))` - and now, there is *no* `ToLower` whatsoever, and the string you're checking *with* is capital cased...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what you call `list`. If you mean the string's char array, use `String.IndexOf`:

```
string test = "Hello Stack Person";
bool contains = test.IndexOf("hello stack person", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

Don't use `ToLower` to compare case insensitively but `StringComparison`.

See: [Does Your Code Pass The Turkey Test?](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html)

Comment: Apart from that, your code should "work" also if you wanted to check if the given string is contained in your test string.